# Proper way to refresh ObjectListView (TreeListView) after removing object from List

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm using ObjectListView (http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/) and trying to update/refresh GUI after removing an object in List. Simple code:

```
 appropriateParent.Entity.Values.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == value.Id);
```

Now, what's the appropriate way to update the TreeListView?

```
treeListView.RebuildAll(false); or
treeListView.RefreshObject(parameterNodeParent);
```

returns "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

Any Ideas?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

[According to the FAQ](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/faq.html#why-doesn-t-the-objectlistview-auto-update-when-i-change-my-model-objects), the  listView does not know when you make a change. Therefor you can do one of the following:

If you can simply reset the iEnumerable by calling `listView.SetObjects(iEnumerable)`, wich will then update the listview.

If all you do is update part of the list you can call `listview.UpdateObjects(iEnumerable)`. Note that this does not know when objects are removed!

If you know wich objects are removed you can remove them by calling `listview.RemoveObjects(iEnumerable)`.

Comment: Not the thing I'm looking for. With `listView.SetObjects(IEnumerable)` I recreate the tree. And I don't want to do that! :) Just "refresh" the leaf section...

Comment: The listview does not know when the list is changed. If all you did was update part of the list you could call `listview.UpdateObjects(iEnumerable)`. However, that does not know when objects are removed. If you know wich objects are removed you can remove them by calling `listview.RemoveObjects(iEnumerable)`.